# Installing Linux on external drive, then booting up a different machine with it

Tags: linux, software-installation, drivers

So I have a machine that I want to install Linux on but for some reasons I won't get into, I can't.

What would happen if I hook up an external drive to my laptop, install Linux on it, then plug that drive in my target machine and try to boot up from it?

Is that possible? Will I have a ton of driver issues etc? 
My gut feeling is telling me that everything will be OK, all I have to do is change the boot sequence in BIOS to boot from the external drive but I can't get over the fact that the hardware will be very different and that might cause problems.

Comment: your gut feeling is telling you something that you should heed. Unless of course these are very similar systems, i.e., same brand, same CPU architecture, relatively similar peripherals and manufacturing dates are not too far apart, probably within the same year. Unless you can satisfy all of these, you are looking into a long series of crashes, kernel panics and inexplicable system freezes.

Comment: @MelBurslan This is completely wrong. As long as the processor architecture is the same, chances are that the installation will work. If something doesn't work, the problem will be that a particular piece of hardware doesn't work, not strange crashes.

Comment: I've worked a couple of months off a live USB thumb drive, without any issues except for the slow booting and the missing graphics drivers (software emulation instead). However, that wasn't an ordinary installation but just an installation medium mounted as a read-only file system. I think there is a hybrid mode where the live system also has persistent data. However, many distros have better tools for getting a live system than installing to an USB drive. Using such an approach, all comments regarding hardware issues are just FUD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this exact thing, and it is quite easy. I followed the guide for [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key) and it works as described. You should follow the instructions for your own distribution of they are provided. Just a few caveats to keep in mind:

- lowest common denominator hardware: if you want it to run in both 32 and 64 bit  computers, install the 32 bit version.
- same goes for graphic cards. Stick to the generic, open source drivers.
- while it will technically work with any external hard drive, unless you have a USB 3.0 device, it will be quite slow to boot and use.
- during the install you will be asked for the location of the boot loader. Make sure it's installed on the external device. Also, given the choice, select the position by UUID and not by device name (e.g. /dev/sda1) since that changes from PC to PC

Answer (score 1):

Modern Linux distributions sport a very minimal kernel, and complete the drivers needed for working by loading modules from a tailored `initramfs`, loaded with the kernel into RAM by the bootloader.

Unless the drivers match, the external drive probably won't boot correctly on the other machine. On the other hand, today's disks drivers are mostly the same, and many other basic devices are the same. So there is a fair chance it *does* work, but no guarantees. You'd have to try.